# How to tell Maven to build an executable jar

Tags: java, maven-2, package

This seems like it should be simple, but I've not figured it out and haven't gotten much help from reading the docs and searching the web.  In an effort to learn to use Maven (2.2.1) with a multimodule project, I've used Maven to create a simple project P with a class C (containing main) and subclass S.  When I run `mvn install` the build runs and produces a BUILD SUCCESSFUL message.  However, when I run the resulting C jar, I get an exception:  "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: P/S"

The directory structure (not showing the src, etc. subdirectories) is:

P
 |--C
 |--S

The pom.xml in directory P currently is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>P</groupId>
  <artifactId>P</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>P</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>P</groupId>
        <artifactId>C</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>P</groupId>
        <artifactId>S</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>  
        <scope>compile</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>P.C</mainClass>
              <packageName>P.C</packageName>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <modules>
    <module>C</module>
    <module>S</module>
  </modules>

</project>
```

The pom.xml in C is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <artifactId>P</artifactId>
    <groupId>P</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <groupId>P</groupId>
  <artifactId>C</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>C</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>P</groupId>
      <artifactId>S</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

and the pom.xml in S is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <artifactId>P</artifactId>
    <groupId>P</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <groupId>P</groupId>
  <artifactId>S</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>S</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

The above are all the latest versions after several attempts.

For this simple learning exercise, the Java classes are:

P/C/src/main/java/P/C.java:

```
package P;

public class C
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
        S o = new S();
        o.sayHey();
    }
}
```

and S/src/main/java/P/S.java:

```
package P;

public class S
{
    public void sayHey()
    {
        System.out.println("Hey!");
    }
}
```

So, how do I tell Maven to include the S class in the C jar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After more research, I've found a means of telling Maven to build a jar file which includes all the needed classes.  The only pom I had to change was in the P directory.  First, the following section had to be ***removed*** from the build-plugins section:

```
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <archive>
        <manifest>
          <mainClass>P.C</mainClass>
          <packageName>P.C</packageName>
        </manifest>
      </archive>
    </configuration>
```

In its place I put:

```
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>create-executable-jar</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>P.C</mainClass>
              <packageName>P.C</packageName>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
```

Answer (score 3):

Maven does not include dependencies in artifacts by default: to run P you still need S in your classpath.

That isn't normally an issue as maven itself uses transitive dependencies: for example, if you have another project depend on P, it will automatically put both P and S in your classpath.

If you want to create a 'uber-jar': a self contained jar containing all dependencies, look at the 'shade' plugin: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  As my answer indicates, I was able to use the maven-assembly-plugin instead of shade.   Also, thanks for reminding me to look at the classpath stuff; along the way to a solution, I verified that my code would run with `java -cp C/target/classes:S/target/classes/ P.C`.

Answer (score 1):

The maven [exec](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html) plugin might solve your problem. You can use it to run the C.jar and it will manage the classpath (and ensure that S.jar is included).

Add something similar to this to your P pom.xml:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            ...
            <goals>
              <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>P.C</mainClass>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
   ...
</project>
```

Then you should be able to run the program like this:

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="P.C"
```

Comment: While I didn't make any changes to my pom, I did try your suggested command; however that just gave me more exceptions.  Do you have details on how to configure the pom to make this work?