# Exec Maven Plugin to Command Line

Tags: java, command-line, smartcard, exec-maven-plugin

I have an application developed in NetBeans/Maven that can be started via command line with:

```
mvn exec:exec "-Dexec.executable=C:\\Java\\jdk1.6.0_33\\bin\\java.exe" "-Dexec.args=-Dlog4j.properties=... -classpath %classpath com.xxx.MyLauncher" -Dexec.classpathScope=runtime -Dexec.workingdir=
```

Now I need to run the application through the standard java command line method, like:

```
java -Dlog4j.properties=... -jar myapp-1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Unfortunately this does not work in the same manner, as I get the following exception:

```
opencard.core.util.OpenCardPropertyLoadingException: property file not found
```

Questions:

- What is the difference between launching applications with the Exec-Maven-plugin and the standard java execution on command line?
- Is there an easy way to convert a Maven execution script to a standard command line?
- How to run the application succesfully?

Comment: does your jar include all the dependencies?  see here for more info: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107988/how-to-tell-maven-to-build-an-executable-jar)

Comment: apparently on commandline you execute the jar as is it was executable, while in pom.xml you give it classpath and mainclass; did you check that your manifest entries match the executed commandline constructed by Maven ?

Comment: It seems that the classpath was the problem, caused by this bug [ http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MASSEMBLY-334]. Replacing the maven-assembly-plugin with maven-shade-plugin resolved the issue. Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the classpath, caused by this [bug](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MASSEMBLY-334).
Replacing the maven-assembly-plugin with maven-shade-plugin resolves the issue.

Comment: Thanks for reporting back. You can accept by now, upvoted question & answer.